# Setting a variable type as Web3 doesn't work in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class that has a variable of type `Web3`, yet when I try doing `provider: Web3` I get the following error:

```
'Web3' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Web3'?
```

Should I follow the error and to provider: typeof Web3 it will simply give it type Object, which is not what I want.

I am currently using :any. What is the best value to set?

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
import { Chains } from "./Chains"

export class Web3Provider {
  provider: any

  constructor(endpoint: string) {
    this.provider = new Web3(endpoint)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `require`? If you do `import Web3 from "web3"` then `provider: Web3` works as expected: https://tsplay.dev/mpL86m.

Comment: did you try provider: typeof Web3?